# How can I increase the size of a sprite inpygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a simple game in python. Unfortunately the sprite images are way too small. How can I increase the sprite image (GrassTile) from 8x8 too 16x16. I am not really sure how to use the transform module.

I have atempted this

```
pygame.transform.scale(grasstile, (16, 16), DestSurface = None): return grasstile
```

And get an invalid syntax

Comment: Are you defining a function, or calling a function? The syntax you've posted seems to want to do both.

Comment: honestly not really sure.Im kinda confused.

Comment: is 'grasstile' a surface or a rect? it needs to be a surface in order to transform it, it is an easy mistake to confuse the two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call your function like this:

```
biggrasstile = pygame.transform.scale(grasstile, (16, 16))
```

(It looks like you just copied the method signature)

Comment: That just gives me the error `TypeError: scale() takes no keyword arguments`

Comment: @enrique2334 do you define grasstile anywhere in your code? That error  makes me think you don't have a var called grasstile at all.

Comment: I do define grasstile in the code. It runs fine unless I try to transform the image.

Comment: I've changed the code in my posting: 'DestSurface = None' is gone because that also just is a way of describing the function and doesn't belong in the function call.